# Changing dev environment to Homebrew

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew

I'm a new mac user and I'm going to start using Homebrew to build my environment. My current environment I've installed piece by piece. What I want to check is what to make sure I do, so I don't get conflicts and i'm not running a load of software that I don't need.

Is this just a case of through the terminal uninstalling, apache, php, mysql etc and clearing out my usr/local/ folder and starting with homebrew?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leave your existing installations in place for the time being.  Homebrew will error if it has to overwrite an existing file in the process of installing a package.

Comment: I did in the end remove everything from my local folder and go with homebrew. It seemed to have gone ok.